# Confluent Kafka S3 source connector is not working - Number of groups must be positive

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka-connect

Confluent Kafka Connect S3 Source connector is not working, its failing with the below error and here is the configuration. Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

config

```
{

"name": 'test_s3_source',

"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnector",
    "s3.region": "us-east-1",
    "s3.bucket.name": "s3-bucket",
    "confluent.license" : "" ,
    "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers" :  "bootstrap-servers",
    "partitioner.class": " io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "transforms" : "AddPrefix",
    "transforms.AddPrefix.type" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.AddPrefix.regex" : ".*",
    "transforms.AddPrefix.replacement" : "test.s3.source"
 }

}
```

Error:

```
 Failed to reconfigure connector's tasks, retrying after backoff: (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1129)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of groups must be positive
```

Comment: Any update here? As I am also stuck with this same exception.

Comment: It looks like it might be talking about regex groups. Your transform would convert every file to have the name "test.s3.storage". You probably want something like "test.storage.source_$0"